# Datatables createdRow function not setting id to row element

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
"createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
    var a = dataIndex;
    alert(a);
    var i = policyInfoArray[dataIndex].id;
    alert(i);

    $('td', row).eq(0).attr('id', i);
}
```

When I run this code, alert(a) pops up correctly and alert(i) gives me the correct result as well. but for some reason

```
 $('td', row).eq(0).attr('id', i);
```

gives me an error when I put i in there. However this:

```
 $('td', row).eq(0).attr('id', 5);
```

works fine. Can someone please direct me as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This seems like a weird jquery selector, can you explain what you are hoping to do with it?  $('td', row)

Comment: Your code is correct but it sets ID to the first `<td>` element. What error do you see in the console? Most likely the problem is in this line `var i = policyInfoArray[dataIndex].id;`.

Comment: That jquery selector is selecting a specific row in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is setting the id to the first `td` element of the table row. If you change the last line of your function to this, it will add the id to the row element itself:

```
$(row).eq(0).attr('id', i);
```

It is likely that the problem you see is to do with the data in your policyInfoArray array.

See working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e9x3f8cf/).

Comment: @Developer Please feel free to up vote if my answer was useful!